# Custom new form not working when list exceeds 5000 items

Tags: 2013, custom-list, list-view-threshold, newform

After 5000 items threshold is exceeded, custom new form stops working even though I did index a couple of columns, and views are working fine, so as default the new form. But when I want to open the custom new form, I get an error.

Read somewhere it might be a problem with the query which should be changed, but I can't find a concrete explanation or example.

Error:

> This view cannot be displayed because it exceeds the list view
>   threshold (5000 items) enforced by the administrator.
>
> To view items, try selecting another view or creating a new view. If
>   you do not have sufficient permissions to create views for this list,
>   ask your administrator to modify the view so that it conforms to the
>   list view threshold.

Comment: Could you please share the error you get in your post? This way, it will be easier for others to help you find a solution.

Comment: Does the custom New form use JavaScript to query the list? If so, is that query trying to return more than 5000 items?

Comment: I pasted information of error message. No, there is no js code in new form for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

So what was necessary to be done in form was to add part of code in query.
This was original code:

```
<Query>
  <Where>
   <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="ContentType"/>
    <Value Type="Text">Item</Value>
   </Eq>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

What I did was adding additional part of query

```
<Query>
  <Where>
   <And>
    <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name="ContentType"/>
     <Value Type="Text">Item</Value>
    </Eq>
    <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name="name of one of indexed columns"/>
     <Value Type="Text">One of its values</Value>
    </Eq>
   </And>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

Additional condition was necessary so I get only couple of values and not whole list of 5000+ items.
Instead of < and > you should put `&lt;` and `&gt;`. " is `&quote;` in new form.

Explanation I found [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c3e42b5e-b17e-43dc-adff-b46984d53875/list-view-threshold-exceeded-affecting-newformaspx?forum=sharepointadminprevious) in similar topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can Increase the List Threshold to fix this issue or use indexed columns , Please see the below article for more info:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37426.sharepoint-troubleshooting-this-view-cannot-be-displayed-because-it-exceeds-the-list-view-threshold-5000-items-enforced-by-the-administrator.aspx

Comment: Thank you for answer, but please read my question before posting. I already indexed columns. View are working fine, only new form is making problem. I don't want to increase threshold as that is not a solution.